# PostgreSQL - regex constraint so that varchar contains only digits

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a column in my PostgreSQL table for phone numbers of type `VARCHAR`. I have chosen this datatype because in my country phone numbers start with a 0.

I need to introduce a constraint to check that the phone number contains **only** digits.

This is what I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE contactInfo ADD CONSTRAINT checkPhone
CHECK(phone NOT SIMILAR TO '%[a-z]%' AND phone SIMILAR TO '%[0-9]%');
```

It seemed to work, but I am afraid it does not filter out characters specific do different languages (like ù û ü â à etc.).

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could be more specific that you want digits only:

```
CHECK(phone ~ '^[0-9]*$')
```

That's even shorter:

```
CHECK(phone ~ '^\d*$')
```

If you don't want to allow the empty string, replace qantifier `*` (0 or more) with `+` (at least one).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the duplicate, the other answered questions were in other languages, not PostgreSQL.

Comment: a phone number can have way more signs. People tend to write it different, but its still valid like "+49(0)1234/567 89 01".  so, eigther include them, or exculde them before comparing like: `CHECK(regexp_replace(phone,'[\/\s\(\)+-]','','g') ~ '^\d*$')`